# OpenCV & C++: global cv::Mat object returns wrong values

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, global-variables

I am trying to use OpenCV in Windows Form. I created a global cv::Mat object and is expecting the object for other functions to use. However every time I initialized the global cv::Mat object and quit/return the function, the values of my global cv::Mat object will change automatically with unknown reason.

One sample code snippet is like:

```
private: cv::Mat *cvImage;
```

For some reason, I created a function called decode() which returns cv::Mat.

```
void copy(){cvImage = &decode();}
```

the cvImage cannot get the correct values by the above codes. Usually is data, dataend, datalimit, datastart and rows being 0 or unexpected values.

Even I tried to use a local variable, say cv::Mat img, to do everything then run     `cvImage = &img;`    , whenever the function quits or returns, the value of cvImage will also change unexpectedly.

I am wondering why would this happen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your use of pointers there creates undefined behaviour. don't use them with Mats !

*DONT* `cv::Mat *cvImage;`

*DO*  `cv::Mat cvImage;`

cv::Mats are refcounted, those pointers will wreck havoc on them.

as a reminder:

```
Mat a,b;  b=a;         // shallow copy, shared pixels (that's probably, what you wanted)
Mat a,b;  b=a.clone(); // deep copy, b will have y copy of a's pixels
```

**Edit:**

"For some reason, I created a function called decode() which returns cv::Mat."

that's your first problem here decode creates a temporary( which gets destroyed after leaving copy() )

void copy(){cvImage = &decode();}

and you return the address of it.

since it seems, that cli can handle only POD objects(like pointers)

1. let decode return a  a Mat*, instead of taking the address of a temp

   Mat * decode() {
      Mat *m = new Mat(100,100,CV_UC8);
      ...
      return m;
   }
2. let copy dlete the old one

   void copy(){
      if (cvImage) delete cvImage;
      cvImage = decode();
   }

Comment: I have thought of your way, but cv::Mat cvImage; cannot use as global variable, as it will say "mixed types are not supported." while compiling. The only way to make to work to define it as a pointer.

Comment: what's your "mixed type" there ? i'm sure, ther's a way to avoid it

Comment: I am not sure, but it gives me an error: "d:\ImageProcess\Form1.h(109): error C4368: cannot define 'cvImage' as a member of managed 'ImageProcess::Form1': mixed types are not supported" whenever I compile using private: cv::Mat cvImage; as global variable.

Comment: It obtains correct values now by using your suggestion. Thx. :)